# Input box font size doesn't work. Can't work out why

Tags: html, css, input, fonts, textbox

Below is the markup:

```
<input type="text" id="username" style="
    font-size: 2vw;
    font-family: inherit;
">
```

and the css:

```
#username {
    font-size: 2vw;
}
```

Problem is that this doesn't work.  I've tried also to change the font-family, which also doesn't work.  I've checked the developer tools in chrome and there's nothing to say that it is overridden or anything.  Even with a style tag it doesn't work.  How do I change the size and family of the font of a textbox?  Other sites just say to modify the attributes directly which I tried and failed.

EDIT:  The fonts and font sizes work when I click within the field.  I want them to work the whole time, not just when I click inside.  There's no scripts attached and the form fields are just submitted within a Form element.

EDIT:  More complete code.  I don't know what else to show apart from this:

```
<form action="/index.php/component/users/?task=user.login&amp;Itemid=101" method="post" class="form-validate form-horizontal well">
                    <fieldset>


<div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label">
            <label id="username-lbl" for="username" class="required" data-content="" data-original-title="" title="">
    Username<span class="star">&nbsp;*</span></label>
                    </div>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" class="validate-username required" size="25" required="required" aria-required="true" autofocus="" aria-invalid="false">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label">
            <label id="password-lbl" for="password" class="required" data-content="" data-original-title="" title="">
    Password<span class="star">&nbsp;*</span></label>
                    </div>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="validate-password required" size="25" maxlength="99" required="required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">    </div>
</div>

                                                                            <div class="control-group remember-group">
                                <div class="control-label">
                                    <label for="remember" data-content="" data-original-title="" title="">
                                        Remember me                                 </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input id="remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" class="inputbox" value="yes">

                                </div>
                                <div class="control-forgot">
                                    <a href="/index.php/component/users/reset?Itemid=101">
                                        Forgot Password?
                                    </a>
                                    <br>
                                    <a href="/index.php/component/users/remind?Itemid=101">
                                        Forgot Username?
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Log in                              </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="return" value="aW5kZXgucGhwP29wdGlvbj1jb21fc3VydmV5JnZpZXc9c3VydmV5aG9tZXBhZ2U=">
                        <input type="hidden" name="d5e9d9bd205a03415af2ff178addfd6f" value="1">                 </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Comment: Have you cleared Cached?

Comment: Just cleared it with same result.  I just don't get why it works only when I click inside the control.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this code in a pen, I get what I would expect with the "vw" unit: 2/100's of the width of the window (iframe for codepen). I don't see the behavior you describe where when the focus is off, it shrinks. Check that your font-size is not on a target like this: `#username:focus {...}`.

Using `vw` for font sizes can be a clever way to make your larger text more responsive. But I like to add a base size to it like: `calc(16px + 1vw)` which tempers the rate at which it grows or shrinks with the viewport of any particular device.

However, for your purpose, using "vw" is likely not what you want to do. I'm speculating here, but you are trying to just make the input text bigger than the body font. It is good practice to first set your body text...

```
body {
  ...
  font-size: 16px; // this defines your "em" size
  ...
}
```

Then you can use that for making adjustments for other sizes...

```
h1 {
  font-size: 4em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

#username {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

For returning back to the original body size without decoupling from body font-size, use "rem"...

```
h1 span {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

The beauty of this method is that you can update one place and all other references will automagically update.

More info than you asked, but I hope it helps you and others.

Comment: HI thanks.  I am using vw because the entire screen needs to be scaled to the window size.

I noticed that the font inside those textboxes change no matter where on the page I click.  As soon as I click anywhere on the page, it becomes correct.  The css doesn't change in developer tools so I can rule that out.  That just leaves scripting, but I'm not using scripts.

Comment: I'm using chrome

Comment: Also, it's only the textboxes that is doing this.

Comment: Only chrome seems to be the issue

Comment: Can you put it in a codepen and have it reproduce what you are seeing?

Comment: ok I'll come back to it.  It's only a small issue but annoying.